SessionNotCreatedException when using llama_index.readers.web.WholeSiteReader inside a docker container
I was using llama_index.readers.web.WholeSiteReader inside a docker container, which first gave a ValueError saying No chrome executable found in PATH. After I installed and setup the google-chrome and chromedriver, it gives SessionNotCreatedException.
Here's how I got the error -
>>> from llama_index.readers.web import WholeSiteReader
>>> test = WholeSiteReader(prefix="https://suryaanshrai.blogspot.com/")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/readers/web/whole_site/base.py", line 40, in __init__
    self.driver = driver if driver else self.setup_driver()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/readers/web/whole_site/base.py", line 57, in setup_driver
    return webdriver.Chrome(options=opt)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 66, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 299, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 354, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x5bdec918dc7a <unknown>
#1 0x5bdec8e70e2c <unknown>
#2 0x5bdec8ea5d6a <unknown>
#3 0x5bdec8ea217b <unknown>
#4 0x5bdec8eecc49 <unknown>
#5 0x5bdec8ee0363 <unknown>
#6 0x5bdec8eb0247 <unknown>
#7 0x5bdec8eb0b9e <unknown>
#8 0x5bdec915424b <unknown>
#9 0x5bdec91582f1 <unknown>
#10 0x5bdec913fafe <unknown>
#11 0x5bdec9158e52 <unknown>
#12 0x5bdec912479f <unknown>
#13 0x5bdec917d638 <unknown>
#14 0x5bdec917d810 <unknown>
#15 0x5bdec918cdac <unknown>
#16 0x7300bd91c134 <unknown>



I am getting the same. I see the browser window opening, the url is not changed by the driver. I am not running in Docker but in an Amazon WorkSpace.
